# I'm new to Laravel and I wanted to convert the SQL query to laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I was trying to use EXCEPT method in Laravel but I was not able to get the result I wanted.

I'm using phpmyadmin and Laravel for my project and it was not hard for the previous few queries. Now I tried converting the following SQL but failed..

```
SELECT name FROM `users`
EXCEPT 
SELECT name FROM `users` as us, `main_user` as ru WHERE ru.id=us.id;
```

The result is filtering the **USERS** table with not the ones present in **MAIN_USER** table. I would really appreciate the help..

Comment: are you use for mysql???  in mysql there is not execpt...

Comment: @scaisEdge I'm using the client of SQL, PHPMYADMIN. I get the results for the above query, but I'm failing to convert to Laravel.

Comment: That is impossible, since mysql does not support except operator.

Comment: @Shadow i understood and you got me into the right discussion. thank you :)

Comment: You may try this.
$main_user_ids = DB::table('main_user')->get()->pluck('id');
$USERS  = DB::table('users')->whereNotIn('id', $main_user_ids )->get();